# Maximum function nesting level when not authenticated

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

From a fresh install on L2, basic auth, no change.
I trying to add some simple route, no auth needed.

Route "/no-auth" works for both logged in and out.

But route "/starter/my-needs", that uses a controller, works only if logged in.

My question is : Why do I get "Maximum function nesting level when not authenticated".
It seems something around the Guest() method turning around...

Here is the controller:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

/**
 * FindMyBank path action.
 */
class FindMyBankController extends Controller {
    /**
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory
     */
    function showMyNeeds() {

        return view('front/findMyBank/FR/myNeeds', array(

        ));
    }//method
}
```

Here the route :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('front/welcome/welcome');
});
Route::get('/no-auth', function () {
    return view('front/findMyBank/FR/myNeeds', array(
    ));
});

Route::group(['prefix' => '/starter'], function () {
    Route::get('/my-needs', 'FindMyBank\FindMyBankController@showMyNeeds');
});

Route::auth();
```

Traces:

```
FatalErrorException in ClassLoader.php line 314:
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

in ClassLoader.php line 314
at FatalErrorException->__construct() in HandleExceptions.php line 133
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in HandleExceptions.php line 118
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php line 0
at ClassLoader->loadClass() in ClassLoader.php line 0
at spl_autoload_call() in ClassLoader.php line 22
in ClassLoader.php line 412
at Composer\Autoload\includeFile() in ClassLoader.php line 301
at ClassLoader->loadClass() in ClassLoader.php line 0
at spl_autoload_call() in ClassLoader.php line 12
in ClassLoader.php line 412
at Composer\Autoload\includeFile() in ClassLoader.php line 301
at ClassLoader->loadClass() in ConnectionFactory.php line 0
at spl_autoload_call() in ConnectionFactory.php line 217
at ConnectionFactory->createConnection() in ConnectionFactory.php line 64
at ConnectionFactory->createSingleConnection() in ConnectionFactory.php line 49
at ConnectionFactory->make() in DatabaseManager.php line 176
at DatabaseManager->makeConnection() in DatabaseManager.php line 68
at DatabaseManager->connection() in Model.php line 3293
at Model::resolveConnection() in Model.php line 3259
at Model->getConnection() in Model.php line 1880
at Model->newBaseQueryBuilder() in Model.php line 1853
at Model->newQueryWithoutScopes() in Model.php line 1823
at Model->newQuery() in EloquentUserProvider.php line 47
at EloquentUserProvider->retrieveById() in SessionGuard.php line 132
at SessionGuard->user() in GuardHelpers.php line 49
at SessionGuard->check() in GuardHelpers.php line 59
at SessionGuard->guest() in AuthManager.php line 292
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php:292}() in AuthManager.php line 292
at AuthManager->__call() in Facade.php line 215
at AuthManager->guest() in Facade.php line 215
at Facade::__callStatic() in 48fdfc9cae67647c36e6877d2cf03c700242912f.php line 56
at Auth::guest() in 48fdfc9cae67647c36e6877d2cf03c700242912f.php line 56
in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath() in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get() in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in a391999563a1000056f17c1ece3bb49d99d7278c.php line 74
in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath() in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get() in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 53
at Response->setContent() in Response.php line 201
at Response->__construct() in Router.php line 1085
at Router->prepareResponse() in ControllerDispatcher.php line 95
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:52}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:103}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then() in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack() in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch() in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 140
at Route->run() in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:52}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:103}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then() in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack() in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute() in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch() in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:52}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\bebankable\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:103}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then() in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle() in index.php line 54
at {main}() in index.php line 0
```

Comment: can you give about your problem more detail? for example what's the output when visiting the desired page?

Comment: and you can always find your error in your logs file

Comment: How are you applying the middleware to your controller/route?

Comment: I add the traces. I don't applying any middleware, but I read that web is used by default here. But my point is, the only difference is the COntroller that is also the very default controller. Route with middleware "auth" works logged in and out.... but I want unsecured route in my cases.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the basic xdebug default limitation,
[PHP.ini]
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250

And it's work.